# Call to a member function add() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting an error while I run this simple insert operation please have a look

> ERROR:
>   A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$mdata
>   Filename: controllers/welcome.php
>   Line Number: 29
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function add() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\codi\application\controllers\welcome.php on line 29

## I created MVC based code using codeigniter

my model names as mdata.php
as:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Mdata extends CI_Model {
function Mdata(){
parent::__construct();
}
function add($id, $name) {
        $data = array(
            'userid' => $id,
            'username' => $name
        );

        $this->db->insert('users', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

---

my controller named as welcome.php is as

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller 
{

public function index()

{
        if($this->input->post('submit'))
        {
            $id = $this->input->post('id');
            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $this->mdata->add($id,$name);
            }

$this->load->model('mdata','',TRUE);

 $this->load->view('data');

}

}
```

=============================================================================
my view file that is data.php as

```
<body>
<?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>

<?php echo form_open('welcome'); ?>

    <p>
        <?php echo form_input('id'); ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <?php echo form_input('name'); ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit'); ?>
    </p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
```

---

Any help me for this simple mistake which I made?

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the model referenced by `$this->mdata` *before* calling `add()`

```
if($this->input->post('submit'))
{
  // load the model first!
  $this->load->model('mdata');

  $id = $this->input->post('id');
  $name = $this->input->post('name');

  $this->mdata->add($id,$name);
}
```